# How do I query a JSON column using where in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to query a json column in the database, however, I am unsure how. I would like to know how to apply "where" to it to query data. for example:

We would use where like this regularly:

```
$data = myModel::where('id', 1)->first();
```

but what if, instead of using the ID column, I'd like to query using a specific property of a JSON column, for example:

```
$data = myModel::where('myJsonColumn['myJsonProperty']', 1)->first();
```

Obviously, what I wrote is incorrect but this is the best way I could explain exactly what I need as I'm still new to PHP Laravel.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#json-where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereJsonContains()` to solve this problem if you are looking for a specific value in the JSON:

```
Model::whereJsonContains('column_name', 'value')->first()
```